# useImperativeHandle way vs useState way

Tags: reactjs

I have a `CountDownTimer` component. This component should be able to get a current `countDownTimerValue` from the parent component and start the timer that way. The parent component disables some components if the countdown has started. This can be implemented in two ways:

1. using states and passing them from the parent component
2. using the useImperativeHandle to pass some functions from the CountDownTimer component

The first implementation looks like this:
CountDownComponent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export type Props = {
  seconds: number;
  decreaseCountDown: () => void;
};

export const isCountDownTimerVisible = (currentTimer: number) => {
  return currentTimer > MIN_TIMER_VALUE;
}

export const MIN_TIMER_VALUE = -1;

const CountDownTimer = ({ seconds, decreaseCountDown }: Props) => {
  const intervalId = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    createIntervalIfRequired();
    return () => clearIntervalIfRequired();
  }, [seconds]);

  const createIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (intervalId.current !== undefined) {
      return;
    }
    if (seconds <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE) {
      return;
    }
    const createdIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      decreaseCountDown();
    }, 1000);

    intervalId.current = createdIntervalId;
  };
  
  const clearIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (seconds > MIN_TIMER_VALUE || intervalId.current == undefined) {
      return;
    }
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    intervalId.current = undefined;
  };

  return (
    <span className={`px-2 ${seconds <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
      {beautifyTime(seconds)}
    </span>
  );
};

const beautifyTime = (time: number): string => {
  let minutes = parseInt((time / 60).toString()).toString();
  let seconds = parseInt((time % 60).toString()).toString();

  if (seconds.length == 1) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  if (minutes.length == 1) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};

export default CountDownTimer;
```

By doing this the parent component should hold the current timer and the logic to decrease the value for this component which I think is something internal to this component and I don't like that this is something that is created within the parent component.

Parent component:

```
 // Other code ...
  {!isCountDownTimerVisible(countDownTimerValue) && t("Send pin2 Request")}
  <CountDownTimer
    seconds={countDownTimerValue}
    decreaseCountDown={() => {
      if (sendPin2Status == "error") {
        setCountDownTimer(MIN_TIMER_VALUE);
        return;
      }
      setCountDownTimer((currentCounter) => currentCounter - 1);
    }}
  />
```

Now let's take a look at the imperative way.
CountDownComponent:

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useRef,
  useState
} from "react";

export type CountDownTimerApi = {
  isVisible: () => boolean;
  setTimer: (seconds: number) => void;
};

export type Props = {
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<CountDownTimerApi>;
};

export const isCountDownTimerVisible = (currentTimer: number) => {
  return currentTimer > MIN_TIMER_VALUE;
}

export const MIN_TIMER_VALUE = -1;

const CountDownTimer = forwardRef(function CountDownTimer({ ref }: Props) {
  const intervalId = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>(undefined);
  const [countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer] = useState<number>(-1);

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        isVisible: () => {
          return countDownTimer >= MIN_TIMER_VALUE;
        },

        setTimer: (seconds: number) => {
          setCountDownTimer(seconds);
        }
      };
    },
    [countDownTimer]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    createIntervalIfRequired();
    return () => clearIntervalIfRequired();
  }, [countDownTimer]);

  const createIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (intervalId.current !== undefined) {
      return;
    }
    if (countDownTimer <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE) {
      return;
    }
    const createdIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCountDownTimer((previousValue) => previousValue - 1);
    }, 1000);

    intervalId.current = createdIntervalId;
  };

  const clearIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (countDownTimer > MIN_TIMER_VALUE || intervalId.current === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    intervalId.current = undefined;
  };

  return (
    <span className={`px-2 ${countDownTimer <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
      {beautifyTime(countDownTimer)}
    </span>
  );
});

const beautifyTime = (time: number): string => {
  let minutes = parseInt((time / 60).toString()).toString();
  let seconds = parseInt((time % 60).toString()).toString();

  if (seconds.length === 1) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  if (minutes.length === 1) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};

export default CountDownTimer;
```

By doing this everything internal to the component is encapsulated within the component. This I like. But the react docs suggests to not use this hook and use states if possible.

Parent component:

```
  // other code ...
  {!countDownTimerRef.current?.isVisible() && t("Send pin2 Request")}
  <CountDownTimer ref={countDownTimerRef}/>
```

Why does React suggest the first solution ([using states instead of useImperativeHandle whenever possible, see Pitfalls section](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle)) whilst the second one encapsulates everything related to the component within the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason why React advises against `useImperativeHandle` whenever possible is because it goes against one of the core philosophies of React: data flow should be explicit and easy to follow. `useImperativeHandle` breaks this convention by allowing parent components to access and manipulate the state of its children directly, bypassing the normal unidirectional data flow.

This may not be a problem for small projects or if used sparingly, but for large projects with multiple developers, it could potentially lead to code that is difficult to understand and maintain. When data changes happen, it would be hard to trace where the changes come from. It could also lead to bugs that are difficult to track down, since any part of the code that has access to the ref can modify it.

On the other hand, when using state and props, the data flow is clear and unidirectional: data is passed down from parent to child through props and changes in child components are communicated to the parent through callbacks.

In your particular case, using `useImperativeHandle` seems to lead to cleaner code since it keeps everything related to the countdown timer inside the `CountDownTimer` component. This is a valid consideration, and there are definitely cases where `useImperativeHandle` can be the better choice.However, even without `useImperativeHandle`, you could still achieve a similar degree of encapsulation by creating a custom hook that handles all the timer-related logic:

```
function useCountdown(seconds) {
  const [countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer] = useState(seconds);
  const intervalId = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    createIntervalIfRequired();
    return () => clearIntervalIfRequired();
  }, [countDownTimer]);

  const createIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (intervalId.current !== undefined) {
      return;
    }
    if (countDownTimer <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE) {
      return;
    }
    const createdIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCountDownTimer((previousValue) => previousValue - 1);
    }, 1000);

    intervalId.current = createdIntervalId;
  };

  const clearIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (countDownTimer > MIN_TIMER_VALUE || intervalId.current === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    intervalId.current = undefined;
  };

  return [countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer];
}
```

### Edit based on comment :

`useCountdown` hook can be used in the `CountDownTimer` component. also adding an isVisible function to the return value of useCountdown, to check if the timer is visible or not:

```
function useCountdown(initialSeconds, onCountdownEnd) {
  const [countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer] = useState(initialSeconds);
  const intervalId = useRef<NodeJS.Timer | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    createIntervalIfRequired();
    return () => clearIntervalIfRequired();
  }, [countDownTimer]);

  const createIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (intervalId.current !== undefined) {
      return;
    }
    if (countDownTimer <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE) {
      return;
    }
    const createdIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCountDownTimer((previousValue) => {
        if (previousValue - 1 <= MIN_TIMER_VALUE) {
          onCountdownEnd(); // invoke the callback when timer reaches the minimum value
        }
        return previousValue - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);

    intervalId.current = createdIntervalId;
  };

  const clearIntervalIfRequired = () => {
    if (countDownTimer > MIN_TIMER_VALUE || intervalId.current === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    intervalId.current = undefined;
  };

  const isVisible = () => {
    return countDownTimer > MIN_TIMER_VALUE;
  };

  return {countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer, isVisible};
}
```

You can then use this hook in your `CountDownTimer` component like this:

```
const CountDownTimer = ({ initialSeconds, onCountdownEnd }) => {
  const { countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer, isVisible } = useCountdown(initialSeconds, onCountdownEnd);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCountDownTimer(initialSeconds);
  }, [initialSeconds]);

  return (
    <span className={`px-2 ${!isVisible() ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
      {beautifyTime(countDownTimer)}
    </span>
  );
};
```

Here, `CountDownTimer` receives initialSeconds as a prop, and passes it to useCountdown. The useEffect hook in `CountDownTimer` ensures that the timer is reset whenever initialSeconds changes. The `isVisible` function is used to control the visibility of the timer.

The parent component would look like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [initialSeconds, setInitialSeconds] = useState(60);
  const [countDownVisible, setCountDownVisible] = useState(true); // Add a new state for the visibility

  const handleCountdownEnd = () => {
    // This function will be called when the countdown ends
    setCountDownVisible(false); // Hide the countdown when it ends
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Other code... */}
      {countDownVisible && <CountDownTimer initialSeconds={initialSeconds} onCountdownEnd={handleCountdownEnd}/>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this case, `ParentComponent` manages initialSeconds which controls the start value of the countdown. When it wants to start a countdown, it can just update initialSeconds, and CountDownTimer will start counting down from that value. Note that initialSeconds doesn't need to be state - it could also be a prop, or calculated based on other values. The important part is that it controls the start value of the countdown.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I would love it if you provided how and where you would use it. in the CountDownCompoenet or in the ParentCompoenent? If you use it in the CountDownComponent how would you expose a function that says the timer is visible or not? Anyways can you please also include the usage?

Comment: If it is used on the parent component then the parent component still hold the data for the countDownTimer value which is something internal to that component I guess.

Comment: Yes , i have added modifications for adding an isVisible function to the return value of useCountdown to check if the timer is visible or not.

Comment: But now the parent component has no way of knowing if CountDownComponent has stopped counting. Unless we move that useCountDown to the parent component. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You are correct. you can solve this by modifying useCountdown hook to accept a callback that will be invoked when the timer reaches the MIN_TIMER_VALUE.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I've learned a lot from you! I have one more question thought. calling setState within a useEffect is an anti-pattern. Because by doing so we perform a useless render. How would you solve that by using this new custom hook?

Comment: Because as the docs mention, useEffect should only be used to have some intercations with an external system or to cleanup those intercations. Setting the countDown is not an external entity and creates a redundant render.